# Empty Java generics

Tags: java, android, generics, android-asynctask, variadic-functions

I realize this issue is somewhat trivial, but I'm interested in knowing the "correct" answer.

I'm trying to extend `android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`,
but my task doesn't require any parameters.

Given that I have to overload `protected Result doInBackground(Params... params)`,
what is the "best" way to pass in no parameters?

Currently, I'm using `Object` as the `Params` type and starting the task with:
`new MyAsyncTask().execute( (Object)null );`
This is totally functional, but I'm new to Java and don't know if this is a good way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do.

Obviously I can't put something like `void` or `null` in for the `Params` field, but if I use a wildcard I'm unsure of what to do about the arguments to `doInBackground(Params... params)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...and then I realized that the answer to this was in the Android Developers reference manual (under AsyncTask).  Anyone interested in more details about this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Void` (note the capital V) for any data types that you do not need. Be sure to use the `@Override` annotation, so the compiler will catch any problems. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Asyncer) demonstrating this.

Comment: Heh, sure, but his answer is a superset of everyone else's (given that the example includes the no-arg method call to execute()).  I appreciate your answer as well, Cristian, for what that's worth to you.  :p

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Void`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) class.

```
android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Void`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) class.  Like so:

```
android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass any parameters to method requiring varargs parameter, simply pass nothing, like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Varargs parameter means "0 or more" values.